# Android Services-when to use Context.bindService vs Context.startService

Tags: android, service

Can any Android experts explain when you would use

Context.bindService vs Context.startService to start a Service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs for [Bound Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

> A bound service is the server in a client-server interface. A bound service allows components (such as activities) to bind to the service, send requests, receive responses, and even perform interprocess communication (IPC).

In other words binding to a `Service` allows two-way interaction by exposing methods in the `Service` which are available through the `IBinder` via a `ServiceConnection`.

In contrast, using `startService(...)` performs more of a one-shot operation. This is only really useful if the `Service` can work in an autonomous fashion, i.e., it knows what it needs to do and doesn't need to be controlled further other than via any action and or data passed in the `Intent` used to start it. In general a `Service` which is started with `startService(...)` will not communicate directly with the component that started it (such as an `Activity`). It can however send data or results of an operation using a broadcast or by creating a `Notification`.

Comment: I really like Squonk's description. It's a real nice simple explanation.  I will however add that it not entirely an "either/or" situation as you can bind to a service that you've started.  Read https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services#Lifecycle .  It gives an explanation why you might use both.